# operate on object with private member function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm basically trying to create a generic object in javascript that I can use to act like an associative array.
But I would like to give the object some custom members to be able to operate on the giving object. Needles to say I'm failing miserably hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is the generic object I'm talking about.

```
function easeArray() {
    this.valIndex = function(searchTerm,object) {
        //searchTerm+object;
        if (searchTerm in object) {
            return "true" + object[searchTerm]
        }
    }
}
```

So then I try to initialize it like this.

```
     var  myCollection = new easeArray(); 
     myCollection = {"dioxanes": 0,  "shunning": 1,  "plowed": 2,
         "hoodlumism": 3, "cull": 4,      "learnings": 5,
        "transmutes": 6, "cornels": 7,   "undergrowths": 8,
        "hobble": 9,     "peplumed": 10, "fluffily": 11,
        "leadoff": 12,   "dilemmas": 13, "firers": 14,
        "farmworks": 15, "anterior": 16, "flagpole": 17};
```

this works fine but when I try to do something like this:

```
  alert(myCollection.valIndex())
```

I get an error. **Type Error: object does not support property or method.**

Never mind that I'm not passing the values into the function I understand that, the function is not even recognize.

My end result is to have a generic object that i can initialize and fill up with key value pairs and then simply say `object.valindex("searchTerm");`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your re-assigning the myCollection variable to a different value - use methods / constructor to pass values

Comment: "Filling" the object with data will be no problem, but as ManseUK said, you not adding anything to `myCollection`, you are overriding it with a new value. If I had an array `a = [1,2]`, then `a = 3` does not add `3` to the array, it just sets `a` to point to `3` instead of the array. That's basic variable assignment. Also I don't see how this has anything to do with "private members" (which do not exist in JS anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work because on latest statement you destroy the instance of your `easeArray` object. Thus the array has not such method defined

try this code instead

```
var easeArray = function(obj) {
    this.obj = obj
    this.valIndex = function(searchTerm) {
        if (searchTerm in this.obj) {
            return "true" + this.obj[searchTerm];  
        } 
    }
}

var myCollection = new easeArray({
        "dioxanes": 0,  "shunning": 1,  "plowed": 2,
        "hoodlumism": 3, "cull": 4,      "learnings": 5,
        "transmutes": 6, "cornels": 7,   "undergrowths": 8,
        "hobble": 9,     "peplumed": 10, "fluffily": 11,
        "leadoff": 12,   "dilemmas": 13, "firers": 14,
        "farmworks": 15, "anterior": 16, "flagpole": 17
    });

    myCollection.valIndex("firers"); /* this returns "true14" */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation im an a recovering actionscript addict and it starting to show. I didnt realize that i was basically overriding the value. I was trying to make a variable to type easeArray which i obviously managed to screw up in more then one way.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code:

```
     var  myCollection = new easeArray();
```

You set the variable "myCollection" to a reference to a new object you've constructed. Then, in the next line:

```
     myCollection = {"dioxanes": 0,  "shunning": 1,  "plowed": 2, ...
```

you set the same variable to a reference to a *different* object. The one you constructed in the first statement is gone at that point.

What you'll need to do is add some methods to your "easeArray" class to allow you to store values  into it according to your needs. Given the examples you've posted, I'm not sure why you need that "valIndex" function.  If you simply reference one of those strings:

```
     var index = myCollection["dioxanes"];
```

you'll see that "index" is 0.